# Expecting errors in rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to expect an error in an `rspec` test.

```
lambda {Participant.create!({:user_id => three.id, :match_id => match.id, :team => 1})}.should raise_error StandardError
```

For now I'm just using `StandardError` to make sure it's working.

```
1) StandardError in 'Participant should never allow more participants than players'. 
   This game is already full.  Cannot add another player.
/home/josiah/Projects/Set-Match/app/models/participant.rb:12:in `do_not_exceed_player_count_in_match'
./spec/models/participant_spec.rb:24:
```

It clearly throws the error, but my test still fails.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your syntax looks correct. To debug this, simplify to make sure your spec is coded correctly.

```
it "should raise an error" do
  lambda {raise "boom"}.should raise_error
end
```

And then add more detail until it breaks.

```
lambda {raise "boom"}.should raise_error(RuntimeError)
lambda {raise StandardError.new("boom")}.should raise_error(StandardError)
```

Answer (score 49):

Since some time, but at least in RSpec 2.5, it is possible to use

```
expect {raise 'boom'}.to raise_error(RuntimeError, /boom/)
```

Answer (score 7):

I had to fight with the same symptoms:

```
def boom
  raise "boom"
end
boom.should raise_error
```

The test above fails because `raise_error` requires `should` to be called on a `Proc` (due to technical reasons, I suppose). Thus, wrapping a method call with a lambda works just fine:

```
  lambda { boom }.should raise_error
```

Unfortunately, the documentation does not say that explicitly and there is no RSpec Exception that reveals this behavior. There is a [two year old ticket](https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/5645/tickets/540-raise_error-should-specifically-indicate-if-should-not-called-on-proc#ticket-540-2) for that.

Comment: "boom.should raise_error" fails because boom is evaluated just before doing the "should"; lambda, in other hand, is called by the "should" itself.